# How to configure custom configuration objects

Tags: c#

I'm trying to register a custom config object, but can't figure out how to configure it. I try to use ServiceCollection.Configure<>(), but gets

> Cannot convert from 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection' to
>   'System.Action'

**LCToolsConfig.cs**:

```
namespace LC.Assets.Core.Utility.Config
{
    public interface ILCToolsConfig
    {
        int SiteId { get; set; }
        IShopsConfig Shops { get; set; }
        ISiteConfig Site { get; set; }
    }

    public class LCToolsConfig : ILCToolsConfig
    {
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        public IShopsConfig Shops { get; set; } = new ShopsConfig();
        public ISiteConfig Site { get; set; } = new SiteConfig();
    }
}
```

**ShopsConfig.cs**:

```
namespace LC.Assets.Core.Utility.Config
{
    public interface IShopsConfig
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShopsConfig : IShopsConfig
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**SiteConfig.cs**:

```
namespace LC.Assets.Core.Utility.Config
{
    public interface ISiteConfig
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class SiteConfig : ISiteConfig
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Configure code**:

```
services.AddSingleton<Configuration>();
services.AddOptions();

Configuration c = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<Configuration>();

services.Configure<LCToolsConfig>(c.GetSection("LCTools"));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

I ended up with binding the section to the object and add register the object as a singleton.

**Code, config**:

```
IConfiguration c = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
var cnf = new LCToolsConfig();
c.Bind("LCTools", cnf);

services.AddOptions();
services.AddSingleton(cnf);
```

**Code, injection**:

```
public StoreController(LCToolsConfig config) { }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just change `services.Configure<LCToolsConfig>(c.GetSection("LCTools"));` to `services.Configure<LCToolsConfig>(() => c.GetSection("LCTools"));`.

`services.Configure<T>()` is looking for a `System.Action` as an argument, and you're passing it the return value from `c.GetSection()` which is a `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection`, not a `System.Action`.

Comment: I've changed it to "services.Configure<LCToolsConfig>(() => c.GetSection("LCTools"));", but still get's an error, saying: "Delegate 'Action<LCToolsConfig>' does not take 0 arguments". I've tried different implementations without luck

Comment: Well then change the action to `(cfg) =>` but I'm not sure what you're supposed to do with the `LCToolsConfig` instance as I'm not familiar with configuration of ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I had to go a different way and Bind the section to the element